# SSIS package from Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis

I need to dump data from Access to SQL database .I just deployed the package into the Integration services catalog and I keep getting the error

The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft jet 4.0 OLE DB is not registered and I tried running the package by keeping the 64 bit to false but I still have the same problem.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8a40d329-0611-44e2-ae51-3bd9b0901754/ssis-the-requested-ole-db-provider-microsoftaceoledb120-is-not-registered?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: So you have an SSIS package which imports data into SQL Server from Microsoft Access? And you are receiving that error when running the SSIS package? Does the import work if you manually import the data through SSMS? If so, and if it then just errors once you have it deployed to the IS catalog, it might mean that your SQL Server "server" doesnt have the OLE DB drivers installed...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure on the computer you are trying to run the ssis package from that the provider you selected in your SSIS package exists. Or change the provider to another one. You may also run into issues with 32 v 64 bit versions.